# how can i add a integer list in grails domain class

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I have created a domain class as given below, which contains an `int` and list of Integer properties.

```
class User {

    int UserId
    List<Integer> UserFriendsId 

    static constraints = {
    }

    User() {
        this.UserId = 21
        this.UserFriendsId=[1,2,3]
    }
}
```

The table generated for this domain class while saving is as follows

```
    mysql> select * from user;
+----+---------+---------------------+
| id | version | UserId              |
+----+---------+---------------------+
|  1 |       0 |                  21 |
|  2 |       0 |                  21 |
|  3 |       0 |                  21 |
+----+---------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

column for `userFriendsId` (ie: for list of integers) is not generated in this table `user`.

so how can solve this issue or can add list of integer in grails domain class.

Answer (score 2):

The UserFriendsId List should be mapped as a [GORM basic collection type](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#basicCollectionTypes) and not simply be a list in the User domain class:

```
class User {

    int userId

    static hasMany = [userFriendsIds: Integer]

    static mapping = {
        userFriendsIds joinTable: [name: "user_id", column: "friend_id", type: Integer]
    }

    static constraints = {
    }

    User() {
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this method but not working.. in this case.. but works in case of string list

Comment: I updated the example to use a joinTable mapping to make sure the mapping does not use a reserved column name.

Comment: You should also note the property names _userId_ and _userFriendsId_ starting with a lower case letter instead of a capital.

Comment: I tried mapping also...like    userFriendsIds joinTable: [name: "user_id", column: "user_friends_ids", type: Integer] but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you turn on SQL logging for the data source? Look at logSql at http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/guide/conf.html#dataSource

Answer (score -2):

Why not just make UserFriendsId a comma separated String?

```
class User {

    int UserId
    String UserFriendsId 

    static constraints = {
    }

    User() {
        this.UserId = 21
        this.UserFriendsId = "1,2,3"
    }
}
```

Then:

```
for (userId in UserFriendsId.get(21).split(','))
{
    println userId.toInteger()
    /// Or do whatever ...
}
```

Comment: So we can't save a list of integer in grails domain class?